# Imported data from CSV is put into wrong mysql column

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import an excel file into my mysql database using CSV.

DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_products` (
  `productID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `categoryID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `brandID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `seriesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `price` double NOT NULL default '0',
  `special` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`productID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`,`info`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='All products' AUTO_INCREMENT=21341 ;
```

First line of CSV:

```
Bottle opener (No.:015005);1;1;0;Blue, metallic;801001.gif;12-05-2012;0.95
```

I use 'import CSV using LOAD DATA', with following columns: name,categoryID,brandID,seriesID,info,img,date_added,price,special

It runs without errors, but the info field is left blank, the info is put into the 'img' field, img into date_added, etc. So it skipped the info field. Why is that?

Comment: Becasue it's got a comma in it? You need to tell mysql that comma isn't a field delimiter, or use quote delimiters around strings when you export excel as csv. e.g. "Blue, metallic"

Comment: The defaults for import have a semi-colon as field delimiter. Why would it think that a , is a field delimiter? Also, that would put 'Blue' in the info field and 'metallic' in the img field, so that can't be what's going wrong.

Comment: not sure, but treating ,as`a delimiter even if you've specified another is a recurring theme. did you try quotes?

Comment: Enclosing all entrees with quotes (") did the trick. Still seems like a PhpMyAdmin bug to me though. 

I used this VB script to export everything: http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/export_excel_csvs_with_double_quotes

Comment: I've seen more than few "fully configurable" csv import utilities over the years not exactly work as advertised, so a bug wouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you save the file as tab delimited text (this is assuming you can modify it with a spreadsheet program), this circumvents the problem of misidentifying commas.